# SQL what will return by simply GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

For SQL, I know the group by usually use with the aggregate function. However, if use alone, what will be return ?

For example:

```
SELECT continent FROM world
GROUP BY continent
```

saying that world is a table with all countries in the world and other info including continent, what will this query return me ?

Thanks!!

Comment: I am sure you can test this yourself, can't you?

Comment: Why do you do a GROUP BY when you use no aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, SUM, COUNT)? Also the general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Newer MySQL versions will raise an error here (unless in compatibility mode), older versions will return an unpredictable result.

Comment: why would you ask some thing that you can check by your self at least test it and ask why this happen and not this?

Comment: I actually tested it and it returned me a randomly table

Answer (score 0):

It will end with error similiar to

> ...is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either
>   an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Beacuse using group by You have to group by all fields selected or use a function like SUM, MAX etc. on them.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return you an error, because when you group by you need items in the SELECT clause to either be the things you're grouping by or aggregate functions.